# Ambiguous use of logInWithUsernameInBackground

Tags: swift, swiftui, back4app

Hi trying to get `Back4App loginInWithUserName` to work with `SwiftUI` and keep getting the following error

> Ambiguous use of logInWithUsernameInBackground

on `PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground($userName, password: $passWord)`

```
struct ContentView: View {

@State var userName: String = ""
@State var passWord: String = ""
@State var authDidFail: Bool = false
@State var authDidWork: Bool = false
@State var editingMode: Bool = false

let storedUserName = "not your father"
let storedPassword = "this is not the password"



var body: some View {
    ZStack{
        VStack{
            Text("WIK?")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .fontWeight(.semibold)
                .padding(.bottom, 20)
            Image("WIK")
                .clipShape(Circle())
            UserNameTextField(userName: $userName, editingMode: $editingMode)
            PasswordSecureField(passWord: $passWord)

            if authDidFail {
                Text("Information you entered was incorrect.  Try again.")
                    .offset(y: -10)
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
            }

            Button(action: {

                //need to check against back4app and set current user variable
                PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground($userName, password: $passWord){
                    (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                    if user != nil{
                        //worked
                    }else {
                        //error
                    }

                }


                if self.userName == self.storedUserName && self.passWord == self.storedPassword {
                    self.authDidWork = true
                } else {
                    self.authDidFail = true
                }
            }){
                LoginButtonContent()
            }
        }
        //vStack padding
        .padding()
        if authDidWork {
            Text("Log in worked")
            .font(.headline)
            .frame(width: 250, height: 20)
            .background(Color.green)
            .cornerRadius(20.0)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .animation(Animation.default)
        }
    }
    //ZStack
        .offset(y: editingMode ? -150 :0)

}
```

}

Tried looking at `$username` and `$password` Strings to pass as `Object[""]: String`

Also tried the String Values  `self.userName` and `self.passWord`

and tried the String Values  `userName` and `passWord`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `String` values, not `Binding<String>`:

`PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(userName, password: passWord)`

Comment: no tried that didnt work - i am trying to get the values from one textfield and securefield into the username and password variable PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(self.userName, password: self.passWord)

Comment: In swift isn't that function `logInWithUsername(inBackground: ...` instead of `logInWithUsernameInBackground(userName, password: passWord)` as per the [documentation](https://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/api/Classes/PFUser.html#/c:objc(cs)PFUser(cm)logInWithUsernameInBackground:password:block:)

Answer (score 0):

found where the error is.  The generated SWIFT API code for Back4App has as  gujci mentioned the wrong function.
Yeah go figure.
Will let them know.

Comment: If you don't mind, can you share your solution here? What documentation were you following?